# Access redux store from background page of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

In my chrome extension I am using redux store to manage local state. For some operation I need access to this store in backround scripts, but I am unable to find a way.

Also setting store in the window object property also not working.

Creating store:

```
const store = window.store = compose(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk, log),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
  (createStore)(reducers)
```

Using via provider:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

But when I try to access it in background scripts,  `window.store` is undefined

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?